# Is there a tabris roadmap

Tags: android, ios, eclipse

my question is about the future development of tabris. Is there any information about that ? A roadmap or similar ? And is there any information for the license model of tabris ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick bit of googling took me [here](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/faq/)

Where the Section 'What are the next steps in Tabris development?' states:

*Currently the development is focused on broadening SWT support and providing extended APIs for mobile devices to access the camera, sensors, data and multi-touch navigation. We will be releasing a beta later this year. The 1.0 release is targeted for this winter.*

and the section 'Under which license is Tabris available' states:

*In the current developer preview phase, Tabris is free to use. Final pricing is not yet available, but our product will be in the same range as othercommercial offerings in the space. We will also offer an enterprise source code license for a flat fee. The RAP server is licensed under EPL v1.0.*

So... it was all there for you to find.

Comment: Actually, after the Site redesign, the Roadmap is now available: http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/roadmap/